# Entity relationship model database

Tags: erd

question: i have to create an entity relationship  model for a company that has 2 managers and 5 sales staff. one manager manages the staff and the other manager oversees the ordering and the stocking of product items.

can someone please tell me if this is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

James Entity must be named as Manager and also
your entity relationship model lacks proper tagging of relationships like 1:M, M:1 or M:M. where M:M is for many to many, 1:M is for one to many, etc.